# EntityManagerFactory instance injection via PersistenceUnit annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Please explain why it's not working. I want to get `EntityManagerFactory` instance by using the `@PersistenceUnit` annotation. No matter what I try it still is null.

I'm not using any Java EE, I run my program through the Java main method. That's why I use a `RESOURCE LOCAL` transaction. As far as I understand it, it is not able to use `@PersistenceContext` but able to use `@PersistenceUnit`

It worked like this but I want to figure out why injection via annotation not working

```
 EntityManager em = 
     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit").createEntityManager();
```

My code:

*persistence.xml*

```
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/shua"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
public class UserDaoImpl {
@PersistenceUnit(name = "persistenceUnit")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

public List<UsersEntity> getAll(){

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();
    Query query = em.createQuery("FROM UsersEntity u");
    List<UsersEntity> users = query.getResultList();
    et.commit();
    em.close();
    return users;

}}
```

*Entity*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public", catalog = "shua")
public class UsersEntity {
    private long userId;
    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;
    private String userEmail;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        public long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "user_name")
        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "user_password")
        public String getUserPassword() {
            return userPassword;
        }

        public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
            this.userPassword = userPassword;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "user_email")
        public String getUserEmail() {
            return userEmail;
        }

        public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
            this.userEmail = userEmail;
        }
```

Comment: Injection requires some kind of container to work. What container are you using? It is not JEE, so is it Spring? CDI? Plain Hibernate will NOT take care of injection for you.

Comment: I thought I dont need container as long as i need inject only persistence unit which i described in xml file   <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">..../>.I assume that this line make this injection and with jpa help this annotation inject entityfactory. And i got confused because http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html its not showing exactlty what they using but still it worked for them.

Comment: Quoting http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html: "Apache TomEE, pronounced "Tommy", is an all-Apache Java EE 6 Web Profile certified stack..." - they're using a *JEE* container